# Transpose or melt to group by columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-melt

I have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "cluster" : ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"], 
                    "col1": ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"], 
                    "col2": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"] })
```

and I can't figure out the best way to have a data frame result with this format

| col | cluster | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | A | 0.4 |
| col1 | C | 0.5 |
| col2 | A | 0.8 |
| col2 | C | 0.75 |

I tried using transpose, then melt the cluster, but didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated!

My desired result is the table - where all columns (except cluster) are rows, and cluster is melt and the average is calculated for the values of the column for each cluster

Comment: Can you show your efforts and also your desired results?

Comment: My desired result is the table - where all columns (except cluster) are rows, and cluster is melt and the average is calculated for the values of the column for each cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a combination of `melt` and `groupby` + `mean` would do the trick. Note that the "col" values are strings in your input, so we also have to convert them to integers first before calculating the mean:

```
out = (df.melt(['cluster'], var_name='col')
       .assign(value=lambda x: x['value'].astype(int))
       .groupby(['col', 'cluster'], as_index=False).mean())
```

Output:

```
    col cluster  value
0  col1       A   0.40
1  col1       C   0.50
2  col2       A   0.80
3  col2       C   0.75
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `cluster` column and calculate mean of each group then `melt`

```py
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].astype(int)

out = (df.groupby('cluster')
         .agg('mean').reset_index()
         .melt(id_vars=['cluster'], var_name='col', value_name='avg')
)
```

```
print(out)

  cluster   col   avg
0       A  col1  0.40
1       C  col1  0.50
2       A  col2  0.80
3       C  col2  0.75
```